# How to translate C record type with char arrays to to Ada record type

Tags: ada

I need to convert several C programs to Ada at the source level, i.e. the whole program to Ada only (not mixed programming calling C code from Ada).

For example:

```
enum { MAXSZFNAME=15, MAXSZLNAME=23 }; 
typedef struct
   {
   char firstname [ MAXSZFNAME+1 ]; 
   char lasttname [ MAXSZLNAME+1 ]; 
   bool ismale;
   } PERSON;
PERSON candidate;
initialse candidate at run-time:
   strcpy ( candidate.firstname, "Fred" );
   strcpy ( candidate.lastname, "Brown" );
   candidate.ismale = true;
initialse candidate at compile-time:
PERSON candidate = { "Fred", "Brown", true };
```

How would I translate the C code example above to Ada?

Comment: You have put several different questions in the same question.  Additionally, how to translate them depends on what the actual problem the C code is solving looks like.  Is it just some code your boss/professor has asked you to rewrite?  Or do you know what problem it is supposed to solve?  If you know what problem the C code is supposed to solve, then I suggest that you describe it.  (One of the benefits of Ada is that it is easier to write your source text in terms of the actual problem, so that may give a better and more readable solution.)

Comment: I have several applications written in C/C that define C/C++ record types. Some of them I wrote more than 10 years ago. The corresponding record objects/variables have to be stored and retrieved from disk. My question is: How do I declare and use 'firstname', 'lastname. and 'ismale' in an Ada record type. It is not a question about how to write applications in Ada.

Comment: Does your new code have to interface with records already written to disk by the old C code? That would be a very different problem from just supporting the same logical structure.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing only one point of your question, for known max-length strings you can use the `Ada.Strings.Bounded` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```c
enum { MAXSZFNAME=15, MAXSZLNAME=23 };
```

as

```ada
type Maximum_Name_Lengths is (Maximum_First_Name_Length, Maximum_Last_Name_Length);
for Maximum_Name_Lengths use (Maximum_First_Name_Length => 15,
                              Maximum_Last_Name_Length  => 23);
```

but I have a feeling it doesn't make sense in the context of your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You declare records like this:

```ada
type Name_Of_Record_Type is
   record
      Name_Of_Field_1 : Type_Of_Field_1;
      Name_Of_Field_2 : Type_Of_Field_2 := Default_Initial_Value_For_Field_2;
      [...] 
   end record;
```

You declare a constant of a record type like this:

```ada
Name_Of_Record_Constant : constant Name_Of_Record_Type
                            := (Name_Of_Field_1 => [some expression],
                                Name_Of_Field_2 => [some expression],
                                [...]);
```

You initialise a variable of a record type like this:

```ada
Name_Of_Record_Variable : Name_Of_Record_Type
                            := (Name_Of_Field_1 => [some expression],
                                Name_Of_Field_2 => [some expression],
                                [...]);
```

You assign to a complete record like this:

```ada
Name_Of_Record_Variable := (Name_Of_Field_1 => Value_Of_Field_1,
                            Name_Of_Field_2 => Value_Of_Field_2,
                            [...]);
```

You assign to an individual component in a record like this:

```ada
Name_Of_Record_Variable.Name_Of_Field_1 := [some_expression];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Max_First_Name : constant := 15;
Max_Last_Name  : constant := 23;

type Person is record
   First_Name : String (1 .. Max_First_Name);
   Last_Name  : String (1 .. Max_Last_Name);
   Male       : Boolean;
end record;

Candidate : Person;
```

This seems quite straightforward, so I'm not sure what difficulty you're having.